# imagecreatefromjpeg crashes on Canon Powershot images

Tags: php, image

I have a upload function which is working fine. However on some images the imagecreatefromjpeg function crashes without giving any error.
After some troubleshooting I found out that this only occurs when uploading photo's that are taken with my Canon Powershot camera. There are other people with the same problem, but I couldn't find a solution so far.

This is the codepart where it goes wrong (it just stops at the imagecreatefromjpeg line):

```
if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
    {
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
    }
```

An example image that fails can be downloaded here:
marcel-verwey.nl/imagecreatefromjpeg_fails/IMG_4844.jpg

Comment: Please `print_r($_FILES)`, are there any upload errors? Perhaps the images are too large.

Comment: How big are your images? Anything in your error logs?

Comment: No, can't find any errors in php_error.log pointing to the php file containing this function. The images are between 2 and 3 MB. Images of the same size but taken with another camera are doing fine..

Comment: Can you provide an example file that crashes, so that other people can test against it?

Comment: @Marcel Verwey, put here a var_dump of the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] value.

Comment: @Danack, the image that fails can be downloaded here: http://marcel-verwey.nl/imagecreatefromjpeg_fails/IMG_4844.jpg

Comment: @josecarlos, this is what the debugger gives me: (string:36) /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php5oND7L
Looks fine to me..

Comment: @MarcelVerwey Works for me. $src = imagecreatefromjpeg("IMG_4844.jpg");
echo "width is ".imagesx($src)."\n";
width is 3264 Tested on both php5.4 and php 5.5

Comment: Hmmm, I am still on php5.2.17 maybe it's fixed in the later versions

Comment: Just tried it with php 5.4, but still no luck.